# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store <1438/02/29> in LateDate Column. Expected type is DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Can not save hjri date "1438/02/29" to date base (only this date)

- SQL Server 2012
- column datatype DateTime2

> error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store
>   <1438/02/29> in LateDate Column.  Expected type is DateTime."

Answer (score 0):

```
Use below conversion it is given hjri date to normal current datetime    
Store data base into below format  
    SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '29/02/1438' , 131)
And get in below format
    SELECT convert(nvarchar(255),'2016-11-29', 131)
```